# Dart Input in VSCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How to get input in dart on vscode?

When I click the "Run" button, it only runs the code on the uneditable-terminal, but when I use the "F5" button to run it, as in Python, it brings an error that I need to do some installation and/or configurations, and it auto-creates a "launch.json" file.

Comment: That's selected in the preferences for the dart/flutter extension.  You can choose the integrated terminal, the debug window (the default), or an external terminal.  I think you're looking for the integrated terminal.  But beware... you lose the ability to invoke debug expressions then.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that your dart sdk is installed correctly and then ensure that you install the dart extension for VS code. That should sort you out.

Comment: https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive If you haven't already install the dart sdk from this link and then ensure that the dart extension for VS code is installed.

Comment: I would suggest that I have all these installed, because other codes which don't require user input, are running just well, but when it comes to getting the user input, that is where the niche is, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` to get into the directory, then open the terminal and run `dart filename.dart`.